# Automating Add Data tool to add 400+ geotiffs based on file extensions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff

I have a spreadsheet that lists the file extensions for 400+ GeoTIFFs that I need to add to ArcMap 10.

Is there a way to automate the "Add Data" function?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write something to add 400 raster layers into your map (and Table of Contents) you might be better to [Create a Raster Catalog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000008z000000.htm) from them so that just one layer results.

Answer (score 1):

Tip search in ArcCatalog (can be mapped drives and search geotiffs only) and drag & drop into an Open ArcMap Document and save.

Though your might find it more efficient to have all those geotiffs loaded into one file geodatabase.